# GORM: How to map Interval to columns?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, jodatime

I have a class similar to the following one that uses JodaTime's Interval class. The Joda Time Grails Plugin does not support the Interval field out of the box, so I tried to map it on my own based on [Rob's suggestion how to persist DateTimeTZ](http://adhockery.blogspot.de/2009/03/persisting-datetime-with-zone.html).

```
import org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInterval
import org.joda.time.Interval

class Offer {

    Interval time

    static mapping = {
        time type: PersistentInterval, {
            column name: "start_date_time"
            column name: "end_date_time"
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot treat multi-column property as a single-column property
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 111 more
```

Does anybody know how to properly map an interval?

Comment: Saw this and was wondering if it might help you out: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4504

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Grails application to try it out on but this works in my J2EE based application:

```
@Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "start_date_time"), @Column(name = "end_date_time") })
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInterval")
private Interval time;
```

Obviously it's not using the niceness of Groovy and GORM... but might be a working solution for the time being.

Comment: Are start_date_time and end_date_time actual fields on your Entity ?

Comment: Nope. start_date_time and end_date_time are columns on the table but are not fields on the Java object. They automatically get mapped to the Interval start and end using this setup.

Comment: What if we want to stick with GORM and not deal with JPA which is where `@Columns` and `@Type` come from right?

Comment: @Jackie This was meant as a workaround to the OP's problem using vanilla JEE instead of GORM. I don't know if the real solution to the problem was ever determined.

Comment: Can you provide the package names for the classes I am still getting compile errors. For some reason it doesn't like the comma separating the two.